# Qt Creator: Clang Code Model hates namespaces when OpenCV added to the project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, qt-creator

I'm writing a program in the Qt Creator (without Qt itself) which uses OpenCV. Everything works, compiles, no problem in that. However CCC does not recognize namespaces, not only 'cv', but 'std' either. What is wrong?) I have 'std:c++latest' turned on, by the way. OpenCV is latest, for MSVC15. The compiler is the same.

[image]

Comment: Check the code model under Tools -> C++ -> Inspect Code Model for hints as to what went wrong. Did you set up the compiler properly for this project? And I have no idea how well this all works under Windows, clang code model with MSVC headers might be problematic.

Comment: @finitegraygreen, where did you find 'Inspect Code Model'? I don't see it. If you mean a message over the list of warning options, it's OK: 'All sanity checks are passed.' All output panels are empty: no error messages. So far I've been working with CCC turned on, many projectes worked perfectly. Well, it's been Qt 5.9 and corresponding Creator version, but I have reinstalled the system and loaded everything for new, and it's Qt 5.10 and Create 4.5.1 now, so can't say anything about it.

Comment: The Linux version has that under Tools -> C++, maybe it is different for the windows version. It opens a separate window with various include path etc. information